# Extremely Low Volume with Bluetooth Headphones

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s, headphones

Currently, when I connect my bluetooth headpones to my phone, the volume is extremely low, even when the volume is set to the maximum level.

For reference, I am using the following:

- Bose QC 35 II headphones
- Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra

The sound issues seems to be present in audio apps (i.e., Spotify, Audible, etc.). Audio during phone calls does not seem to be affected. Initially, I thought that it was something wrong with the headphones. However, when I connect another set of bluetooth headphones (a pair of Westone earbuds with the bluetooth cable), the same issue is present. I have also connected the Bose headphones to my wife's phone (same model) and the issue is not present. I have also connected the Bose headphones to two different laptops and, again, the issue is not present. This leads me to believe the issue is with my phone.

The question is whether or not there is some setting that has been altered to cause this issue. I am aware of the "Disable absolute volume" setting that is mentioned in various blog posts. This setting is currently enabled but seems to have no affect on this issue.

I figured I would ask here before performing a system reset to see if that helps in any way (which is kind of a pain).

Comment: @Robert - As mentioned above, I have already tried altered the "Disable absolute volume" setting but doing so has no affect on the issue.

Comment: Correct. When reading your question I thought the setting had a different name and thus missed that you already mentioned this option.